# DNS lookup failed for kafka - ERROR kafka.conn:conn.py

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-python

I am getting the following error:

WARNING  kafka.conn:conn.py:1527 DNS lookup failed for kafka:9092, exception was [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution. Is your advertised.listeners (called advertised.host.name before Kafka 9) correct and resolvable?
ERROR    kafka.conn:conn.py:315 DNS lookup failed for kafka:9092 (AddressFamily.AF_UNSPEC)

And : 2022-12-07T20:06:57+0000|/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kafka/conn.py:418|ERROR|Connect attempt to <BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=kafka:9092  [IPv4 ('171.15.0.1', 9092)]> returned error 111. Disconnecting.

My docker compose: is the following

```
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    networks:
      - app_network
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    ports:
      - 22181:2181

  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    container_name: kafka
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - 29092:29092
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:29092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
  networks:
    - app_network

  pythonapp:
    build: ../../
    container_name: myapp
    networks:
      - app_network
    depends_on:
      - kafka

networks:
  app_network:
    driver: bridge
```

And My python consumer code is the following:

```
    def kafka_consume(self):
        consumer = KafkaConsumer(
            self.topic_name,
            auto_offset_reset='earliest',
            bootstrap_servers=['kafka:9092'],
            api_version=(0, 10),
            consumer_timeout_ms=1000
        )
        consumer.subscribe([self.topic_name])
```

Any idea?

The ping inside the kafka container works properly.

Comment: You need to add your Python app to the same compose file

Comment: they are in the same docker-compose

Comment: And how are we supposed to know this from your question? Have you tried `docker exec` into your Python container and simply `ping kafka`? Are you using a custom `network` for either service?

Comment: Yes `ping kafka` inside the docker container works properly.  I am using the same `network networks:
  app_network:
    driver: bridge`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your full compose file and your python consumer code